# PHP while(1) time based

Tags: php

I am working with GeoLocation from browser, which works great, I am looking for a way to update the location of the browser every let say 10 minutes. I can't use Cron Job, is there a way that I can specify a while loop in PHP that occurs every 10 min while the user has the browser open?

Comment: Maybe look into html5 sockets ;)

Comment: websockets or polling are your best bet

Comment: PHP doesn't run at all while the browser is open.  You need to use Javascript.

Comment: You'll probably want to do long polling with Ajax.

Comment: You can't do persistent loops in PHP, and that isn't the solution to this problem anyways. You should just initiate AJAX submissions every 10 minutes from the client.

Comment: Why do you need to do it server-side with PHP and not client-side with JS?

Comment: Use browser-side polling, and note that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` has a [timeout option](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html#options) that lets you specify that the device can use cached info if it is recent enough.

Comment: I don't know if  you want to, but you could refresh the page... `header("refresh:600;url=mypage.php");`

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to do this with PHP, if this is even possible with php only.

You could use an endless loop, and a sleep of 10 minutes, but again, this is not the way. This is not what php is made for, its serverside. And besides that, php can not ´undo´ previous send information. You will encounter all kinds of problems. What if you update the script? All current users wont see the new page because their version is loaded in the memory of the server. And than there is maximum execution time...

---

You are looking for an AJAX solution with a javascript timeout with 10minutes. Because javascript is clientside its allot easier to tell thje server 'ok, im ready for new info now'

---

If you are looking for a more global solution, you could make a line in your database, make a table called for example 'timed_scripts' with 3 columns `id, time2execute, script2call`.
Then make the user trigger a function which checks all time2execute values to see if any is smaller than present time, if you, callback the script and update the time to time()+10min

Answer (score 0):

The best method off the top of my head would be to create a PHP script that checks and set a javascript or HTML5 callback to call that PHP script. If an update needs to be made reload the browser, if not continue.

Answer (score 0):

If geolocation code is in JS then seTtimeout(), if the logic is in PHP send ajax request to that logic page in every 10 mins using SetTimeout.